# check validity of touch precisely

Tags: android, surfaceview

I am trying to make an app whereby a picture will be shown, there're a few objects that user needs to identify (i.e. a cup), by touching the cup in the picture on the screen, a circle will be drawn if it's valid.

So far, I have a surfaceview with a bitmap as drawable to be displayed full screen, and upon touching the screen, a circle will be drawn to the view.

I could only think of getting the coordinate of the cup manually in the picture(hardcoded), and check it against the coordinate from touch `event.getX()` and `event.getY()`. But this would not work as screen resolution changes.

What is a better way in doing so? It's like I'm trying to find a way to precisely allow touch on certain areas which I've defined in my app.

Comment: In regards to all the answers so far, I'm sure I read somewhere that android scales up/down all pixel values so that the code only has to work with 480x320, on 1.6 and above anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the coords as you were suggesting but adjust them based on the size of the SurfaceView vs. the size of the BitmapDrawable.  For example, if you know a given area is 100px from the left, you could take your scale as surfaceView.getWidth() / bitmapDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth().  Multiply your scale times your value (100px) to get the final position.  If you're keeping the same aspect ratio on the image, you need to get your scale from the larger of the two (width vs. height) and use that same scale for height and width.

Answer (score 0):

In a given resolution, is the location of cup fixed or it varies there as well.

Also, what about the orientation (landscape, portrait)? does the location change accordingly as well?

There are standard resolutions, so you can always think of mapping the location with resolution.

Also, you can get X, Y coordinate and check if it falls within a range based on height and width of cup image.

Answer (score 0):

First of all find out the size of screen (screen dimensions).

Now place objects relatively corresponding to your screen area.

eg. keep cup on SCREENWIDTH - 60 and check coordinates of touch similarly.